# vim omnicomplete doesn't suggest the class properties

Tags: php, vim, ctags, omnicomplete

I am trying to get vim´s omnicomplete feature to suggest class properties in addition to methods.

The tags file generated by ctags does contain the variable info, so it should be able to show this, but I only get the methods.

class.php:

```php
<?php
class Thing {
    public string $name;
    public function run(){}
}
```

code.php

```php
<?php
require_once "class.php";

$thing = new Thing();
$thing->#cursor here, pressing <C-X><C-O> reveals only run( f ) - not name
```

tags:

```
Thing   class.php   /^class Thing$/;"   c   language:PHP
name    class.php   /^    public string $name;$/;"  v   language:PHP    class:Thing typeref:unknown:string  access:public
run class.php   /^    public function run(){}$/;"   f   language:PHP    class:Thing access:public   signature:()
secret  class.php   /^    public function secret(){}$/;"    f   language:PHP    class:Thing access:public   signature:()
```

generated with: `ctags --fields=+aimlS --languages=php --PHP-kinds=+cdfintv class.php`

.vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
filetype plugin on
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
```

open vim with: `vim -u .vimrc code.php`

**Edit:**

The docs say that it should complete both methods and variables for a class after `->` - so what I am looking for should work.

> after "->" complete only function and variable names specific for
> given class.

- https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ft-php-omni

**update:**

it seems the problem is caused by vim (or it's built-in plugins) not being updated with the latest syntax for php. only untyped properties are shown:

[image: screenshot of vim with omnicomplete menu, untyped properies are suggested, but not typed properties]

Comment: [vi.se] would probably be a better place to ask.

Comment: @Friedrich that is just a mirror, it was updated in 2021: https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3172 I've looked around for an alternative, but I can't seem to find a drop-in replacement for `omnifunc`

Comment: Sorry, I googled faster than I could think. FWIW, I can reproduce your issue with `vim --clean`, *without* a tags file and with `omnifunc` set to its default by PHP filetype plugin.

Comment: `syntaxcomplete#Complete` doesn't use a `tags` file anyway.

Comment: @romainl are you sure? according to this, it uses a tags file for some languages (like C and PHP) if a tags file is present: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Omni_completion 
and if I remove the tags file from my example then it won't even suggest methods for `<C-x><C-o>`, instead saying "Pattern not found"

Comment: dropping the property type in class.php makes it work. typed properties has been in the language since v7.4 (released in 2019) so I'd kind of expect it to be supported

Comment: FYI the completion function is [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/autoload/phpcomplete.vim). omnifunc set from vimrc is overridden in filetype plugin [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/ftplugin/php.vim#L56).
you can check the omnifunc value by running `:verbose set omnifunc?`

Comment: @Levi yes, it looks like tags file is used. Check if tags file has the correct tag for members. If not, may be try to regenerate tags with newer ctags version

Comment: the tags file does contain the typed properties, i am using the latest version of ctags universal

Comment: the dev informs that the tags file is only used to locate declarations in required files, but that the plugin itself does the code parsing to determine the suggestions for completion: https://github.com/shawncplus/phpcomplete.vim/issues/131